# Add-ins not loading when opening MS Access 2007 a second time

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have some add-ins that are used with an MS Access 2007 .accdb application. 
When I open the .accdb file --the first time-- (after logging into the PC), 
the add-ins initialize/load successfully. If I then close MS Access 2007, the 
second (and subsequent) time(s) I open MS Access 2007, the add-ins do NOT 
initialize/load.

They will initialize/load, however, if the user clicks on the MS Office Button > Access 
Options > Add-ins > "Manage: COM Add-ins" > [Go...] > [OK] (Or [Cancel])

1. Is this a bug? Is this expected?
2. Is there some way (with VBA code) to force the Add-ins to initialize/load?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you running more than one version of Access on this computer? I've had similar mixups of A2003 add-ins when I ran A2007 after I'd opened A2003 and left it open. Exiting and letting the version you're using reconfigure itself would take care of the issue in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is some knid of permissions problem.   Possibly the users don't have update/create/delete permissions to the folder in which the add-in is installed.